# How can I access the customized links from the Google app on my computer?

Tags: google-search

I have the Google app on my iOS device, which shows customized links on the home screen along with the Google search bar like the one below.

How do I access the same page on the web (PC)?

[image: App landing page showing search bar, weather, and an image for an article]

Comment: This question shouldn't be migrated from [su] to this [webapps.se].

Answer (score 2):

Exploring the landing page in the app lead me to this [Support article](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9626891?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&oco=2), which says it's not possible to see the suggested articles on desktop.

Your only option is to find the article on mobile and move it to your computer, which can be done in a number of ways depending on your setup: bookmarks, reading list, history, share menu, airdrop, etc. For articles that I want to read once, reading list is the best option. You can add to it from the landing page by just long tapping on the article.

Comment: These might be related: [Add & customize your Search widget  | Google Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/9208897?hl=en&ref_topic=3036131&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=0), [Manage app info from your devices | Google Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/9503395?hl=en&ref_topic=3036131&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=0),  [Change your Discover settings | Google Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/9507369?hl=en&ref_topic=3036131&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=0)